# Python aiohttp - поймать событие закрытия/обрыва websocket соединения

Tags: python, asyncio

Необходимо при закрытии/обрыве websocket соединения освободить ряд ресурсов, которые были открыты в результате подключения, единственное что удалось найти в документации по `aiohttp` это поле `closed` в классе `WebSocketResponse`.

Comment: Вот же ж готовый пример: http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.6/web.html#websockets Смотреть на строчку `elif msg.tp == aiohttp.MsgType.close:`